# How to import numpy in pypy sandbox

Tags: python, numpy, sandbox, pypy

Pypy has a fork of numpy. How to use it in the **pypy sandbox**?

The sandbox prompt 'No module named numpy'.

However, when I tried to copy the numpy library in the lib_pypy directory, I received this error message. Is there a way to import the numpy in pypy **sandbox**?

```
import numpyTraceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/bin/lib_pypy/numpy/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
    its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
    your python interpreter from there.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't import numpy in a sandboxed PyPy at all, sorry.

This is the case for almost all extension modules.  Sandboxing in PyPy is a good proof of concept, really safe imho, but it is only a proof of concept.  It seriously requires someone working on it.  Before this occurs, it can only be used it for "toy" examples: programs that import mostly nothing (or only pure Python modules, recursively).

Comment: @yonexer Authoritative answer from a lead developer.

Comment: Added in the FAQ: http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#module-xyz-does-not-work-in-the-sandboxed-pypy

Comment: Are there any plans to allow module imports in future with the revival of the sandboxing feature (https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2019/08) or is this technically not possible at all and will never be possible?

Comment: The 2019/08 work made sandboxing more powerful, but still importing a random C extension module with the C-API compatibility will never work safely.  In some hypothetical future, numpy *might* be rewritten in some other format than a large amount of C (by people outside of pypy) which would open the door to sandboxing it (as well as many optimizations) in pypy.